# how to make template function for this?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two functions that are very similar and i'd like to make a template function from them.

```
void func1(vector<vector<vector<struct1_type> > > &struct1_x, const int &x,
const int &y, struct2_type &struct2_y, list1<struct1_type> &l1)
```

and

```
void func2(vector<vector<vector<struct1_type> > > &struct1_x, const int &x,
const int &y, struct2_type &struct2_y, list2<struct1_type> &l2)
```

The functions do the same thing...the only thing that differs is the last parameter, which are two different classes for how to handle lists.

I've tried numerous things with no results and hoards of errors. Thank you for any help you can offer a relative newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would declare a function template that generalises your two function declarations:

```
template <typename L>
void func1(vector<vector<vector<struct1_type> > > &struct1_x, const int &x, const int &y, struct2_type &struct2_y, L &q1)
```

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

This is what `template template`s were invented for.

```
template <template <typename> class list_type> 
void func1(vector<vector<vector<struct1_type> > > &struct1_x,
           const int &x,
           const int &y,
           struct2_type &struct2_y,
           list_type<struct1_type> &q1);
```

Note however that the template has to match *exactly*. For example, you couldn't use `std::list` for the `list_type` parameter because it does not take one template parameters -- it takes two: the contained type and the allocator type.

It might be simpler to go with the straightforward, non-`template template` solution.

```
template <typename list_type> 
void func1(vector<vector<vector<struct1_type> > > &struct1_x,
           const int &x,
           const int &y,
           struct2_type &struct2_y,
           list_type &q1);
```

And expect the user to specify `list1<struct1_type>` as the template parameter. This is what [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/), [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/) and [`std::priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/) do.